# Linux Terminal Exit Terminal if last command is executed successfully

Tags: node.js, linux

I have problem that i need to exit terminal if last command is executed successfully...i have this commands in this order and need when application.js is started to exit console...but when i run this all commands i get killed application.js after it is started and is not in this order...i run application with node application.js so killall -9 node actually kills it...how to make order to execute in order and last check if is node running my application.js to exit console....

```
killall -9 node & killall -9 ffmpeg && node /root/application.js && exit
```

I try on end to use && exit and || exit but it executes first when i run this command in terminal and it exits Immediately.

Comment: What are the `killall`s supposed to do?  Are they part of your application or part of your approach to exit after success?

Comment: Normally I'd say just use `(… whatever script you are using …) && exit`.  But from what you write I get mixed messages on whether you already tried that or not.

Comment: Is the single `&` after `killall -9 node` intended or a mistake?

Comment: I make on my portal when i press reinstall to copy files on other server and kill node and ffmpeg and then start my application.js that send api to my main server and after application.js is successfully started it needs to exit terminal because i im using ssh2 for node that is waiting exit command so that can close ssh2 communication with remote server and continue to work on main server

Comment: Are you aware that calling `ssh user@host command` will execute the command on the remote host *and then terminate the connection*, so there is no open terminal lingering?  Maybe that already solves your issue:  `ssh user@host <<EOF`, `killall -9 ffmpeg`, `node /root/application.js`, `EOF`.

Comment: I don't understand you Alfe...could you please write example line that i need to put into my ssh2.exec('SSH command here that i put in above');

Comment: You should have provided your JS code.  How about: `ssh2.exec('node /root/application.js');`?  This *will* terminate after your command finishes (independent of any exit code).  So if you use this, I'd rather expect you to ask a thing like `How can I leave it open in case of an error`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out..i fixed it by calling remote server restart using two ssh2 sessions..now it work..it won't work on one session because of background process doing stuff like copy files installing mysql files etc..so when ssh2 session1 finished all copying it send close event and then is fired ssh2 session2 that restart my node application.js and now it works all